# Unable to reach Adonisjs hello world api through remote/external connection

Tags: adonis.js

I want to try out adonisjs api framework.  I set up a VPS in the cloud.  I SSH into the machine and installed nodejs then ran these command based on the `hello-world` guide on the adonisjs website

```
npm init adonis-ts-app@latest hello-world`
cd hello-world
node ace serve --watch
[ info ]  building project...
[ info ]  starting http server...
[1634733369694] INFO (hello-world/1547964 on li1953-23): started server on 0.0.0.0:3333
[ info ]  watching file system for changes
╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                 │
│    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:3333        │
│    Watching filesystem for changes: YES         │
│                                                 │
╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

To test, I opened another terminal window, SSH to my vps machine, and I ran this command:

```
curl http://example.com:3333/
```

I got this response:

```
{"hello":"world"}
```

This is perfect so far.

Then I went to my web browser and typed in the url `http://example.com:3333/`.  But the web browser gives me unreachable error.

How do I get adonisjs to accept remote connections?

---

UPDATE
I have a temporary solution by setting up an apache server with the following vhost entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
<Location / >
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    Options           +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    ProxyPass         http://127.0.0.1:3333/
    ProxyPassReverse  http://127.0.0.1:3333/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is the curl command done from the external computer? Not the one that has adnonisJS installed?  The reason I ask is because CURL defaults to -GET, so in this case the browser is not actually doing an -GET call.  You could install an extension for REST calls on the browser and try again.

Comment: And this machine is reachable from outside? Meaning you can ping it from an external computer?  (Forget that you have adonisJS installed on it).   Just testing the connectivity against the VPS external access..

Comment: Yes it is reachable from outside.  In fact, I updated my question to show that I installed apache and configured reverse proxy as a temporary solution. But would be great if there's some adonisjs setting that allows external connections without relying on a proxy server.